# Integral closure of an ideal of a domain $R$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

If $R$ is an integral domain, an element $r$ in $R$ belongs to $\displaystyle \overline {I}$, where $\displaystyle \overline {I}$ denotes integral closure of ideal  $I$, if and only if there is a finitely generated $R$-module $M$, annihilated only by zero, such that $\displaystyle rM\subset IM$.

The integral closure of an ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$ is the set of all elements $r$ in $R$ that are integral over $I$: there exist $\displaystyle a_i\in I^i$ such that
$\displaystyle r^n+a_1r^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{n-1}r+a_n=0$.

One direction is not hard, but I have difficulty to find such finitely generated $R$-module $M$. Any hints?

Comment: Can you remind us what is "the integral closure of an ideal"?

Comment: This is Corollary 1.1.8 from Huneke and Swanson, *Integral Closure of Ideals, Rings, and Modules*.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for the reference.